# how to remove rows with less than 3 letter?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark data frame with many rows. each rows is a text. there is just one column. I want to delete or remove rows with less than 3 letter. for example in the following 4 rows I want to remove the second column and 4th. (`pdf` and `a`):

```
this is a text
pdf
a
No ways
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter using the length of the column:

```
df2 = df.filter('length(col) > 3')
```

If spaces matter, you can remove them first:

```
df2 = df.filter("length(replace(col, ' ', '')) > 3")
```

Comment: it will not change spaces in df? because I have one space in front of all rows.

Comment: @Nagh no it won't. The replacement only applies to the filter, but not the dataframe.